# How to iterate through Android ListView to get RatingBar values?

Tags: android, database, listview, android-cursoradapter, ratingbar

I have created a custom `CursorAdapter` which binds some view items (a `TextView` and a `RatingBar`) in a `ListView` to some columns in a `SQL` `database` via `bindView()`, i.e:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    ...

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDbAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
        RatingBar rating = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.life_bar_rating);
        rating.setRating(cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDbAdapter.KEY_RATING_VALUE)));
    }

    ...
}
```

I want to get the absolute latest version of all of the `RatingBar` rating values so I can update the `database` accordingly (in one go). I was initially trying to use the `cursor` in my `CursorAdapter`, however I noticed that the `cursor` just contains the values stored in the `database` and not the latest user changes - is this expected (the documentation is a bit vague)?.

I am guessing I need to iterate through the actual views somehow - how would I iterate through my `ListView` to retrieve all of the new rating bar rating values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make your `Cursor` `final` in `onBindView()`, create field `HashMap<id, rating> mRatings;` in your `CursorAdapter`

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener {

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        ...
        rating.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
        rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromTouch) {
        Integer position = (Integer) ratingBar.getTag();
        Cursor c = getCursor();
        c.move(position);
        int id = cursor.get id;
        mRatings.add(id, rating);
    }
```

And later you traverse `mRatings` and update changed ratings in one transaction.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. How can I get the right cursor row ID for the rating bar? When I try to get the row ID from the cursor passed in as an argument to bindView, I just get the row ID of the last bound ratingBar.

Comment: Actually, it is OK. I just realised I can set a tag and retrieve the tag later on the RatingBar.

Comment: Was editing the post, while you found the way, also I suggest you that your Adapter implements `OnRatingBarChangeListener` so you don't need to create new one for every `RatingBar` and save memory.

Comment: In case you map integers to integers, consider using [SparseIntArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html) for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is expected, because when `bindView()` is called, you are retrieving the value from the DB and updating the `RatingBar`.

So when the user changes the value you'll have to update the DB for each rating bar separately.

So you have to set a `OnRatinBarChangedListener`.

```
rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
        boolean fromUser) {

        if(fromUser){
             //update value here
        }                     

    }
});
```

Notice that we're checking if the change is **fromUser** so as not to trigger the listener on every `bindView()` call.

Comment: Thank you! - is it OK to update the DB every time the user changes a rating bar value? Would this not have an impact on the flash memory in the phone (as I thought it had a certain number of reads and writes)?

Comment: I'm not the hardware expert but I don't suppose it would. Think of a chat application and the huge amount of reads/writes it makes...